# Hide listing of certain files/directories after git pull?

Tags: git, shell, terminal

Often times when I pull from a project, there will be sections or files that have no affect on my work and just bloat my terminal window:

```
Counting objects: 100, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 29), reused 72 (delta 19)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From github.com:Foo/bar
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by recursive.
/js/i_care_about_this_file.js                     |  2 +-
/php/i_care_about_this_also.php                   |  4 +-
/flash/some_project/file_i_dont_care_about.swf    |  Bin 0 -> 904 bytes
46 files changed, 22 insertions(+), 64 deletions(-)
create mode 100188 /flash/some_project/file_i_dont_care_about.swf
```

Obviously this a very short example—there's usually hundreds of SWF files that I'd rather not have show up when I pull.

Is there a flag I can pass to either `git pull` or `git merge`? Or some configuration parameter I can set in either git or my shell?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously git doesn't know what you care about and what you don't, but you can make it shut up entirely by passing `--quiet`.

Also, git is not really designed to handle binary files like SWFs.  Why are you checking them in?

Comment: adding on that, `git` is designed to handle _differences_ in files, and `.swf`s are just another type of files. what fails is that the binary nature of `.swf`s makes changes look like 90%+ of the file changed, so with every change `git` stores almost the whole file again and again, which radically increases the size of the repository.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `-q` switch:

```
        -q, --quiet
       This is passed to both underlying git-fetch to squelch reporting of during transfer, and underlying git-merge to squelch output during
       merging.
```

or I guess more what you want `-n`

```
   --stat, -n, --no-stat
       Show a diffstat at the end of the merge. The diffstat is also controlled by the configuration option merge.stat.

       With -n or --no-stat do not show a diffstat at the end of the merge.
```

is you want to hide just `.swf` files I guess you'd have to pipe `git pull` output to `sed` or `grep`, like:

```
$ git pull <remote> | grep -v ".swf "
```